# Python results output to txt file

Tags: python

I tried this code posted 2 years ago:

```
import subprocess  
with open("output.txt", "wb") as f:     
    subprocess.check_call(["python", "file.py"], stdout=f) 

import sys 
import os.path  
orig = sys.stdout
with open(os.path.join("dir", "output.txt"), "wb") as f:
    sys.stdout = f     
    try:
        execfile("file.py", {})     
    finally:
        sys.stdout = orig
```

It hangs up the terminal until I ctl-z and then it crashes the terminal but prints the output.
I'm new to coding and am not sure how to resolve. I'm obviously doing something wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Betsy. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Why don't you edit the question to indicate what it is that you are trying to achieve. If you copied the code from another question it would be good to include a link to it. We also ask that all new posters read these guidelines. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Best wishes with your Python studies.

Comment: It sounds like you may be using Python 2.x. If so, please add a "python-2.x" tag to your question (and take the word "Python" out of the question's title). I say this because `exefile` doesn't exist in Python 3.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have Python 3.7 and that was probably why it was crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply open and write to the file with `write`.

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('output text')  # You can use a variable from other data you collect instead if you would like
```

Since you are new to coding, i'll just let you know that opening a file using `with` will actually close it automatically after the indented code is ran. Good luck with your project!

Comment: @Betsy No problem, glad I could help :) If this is what worked for you please mark it as the answer that was most helpful to you :)

Comment: Thank you. Sorry just figuring this all out!